# Airflow delay between catchup instances

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the below dag settings to run catchup from 2015. For each execution date the task instance completes in under a minute. However, the next day's task starts only in 5 minute windows. E.g. 10:00 AM, 10:05 AM, 10:10 AM etc. I do not see a 5 minute interval specified for task instances. How can I modify the dag to trigger as soon as the previous instance finishes?
I'm using Airflow Version 1.9.0

```
default_args = {
   'owner': 'ssnehalatha',
   'email': ['ssnehalatha@metromile.com'],
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'start_date': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
   'on_failure_callback': jira_failure_ticket,
   'trigger_rule': 'all_done',
   'retries': 1,
   'pool': 'python_sql_pool'
}

dag = DAG('daily_dag',
           schedule_interval='15 1 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5',
           default_args=default_args,
           dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=24),
           catchup=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this is connected to the scheduler settings in `airflow.cfg`.

```
[scheduler]

# The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 60
```

**EDIT**

The docs for the two parameters you mentioned (from https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md):

> **min_file_process_interval** After how much time should an updated DAG be picked up from the filesystem.
>
> **dag_dir_list_interval** The frequency with which the scheduler should relist the contents of the DAG directory. If while developing +dags, they are not being picked up, have a look at this number and decrease it when necessary.

Seems to me they are more for detecting changed and new DAG *files* as opposed to executing *tasks*.

Comment: Thanks. I see two attributes set to 5 minutes in airflow.cfg under [scheduler]. I believe the first one is causing the delay. Will test and update the result here.


min_file_process_interval = 300
dag_dir_list_interval = 300

Comment: Updating min_file_process_interval to 60 got my catchup jobs to get triggered every minute. I had scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5 even when the task instances were triggered every 5 minutes.

Comment: To be specific, earlier, if the dag for 2015-01-01 started executing at 10:00 am and completed at 10:01 am, the dag for 2015-01-02 will get triggered only at 10:05 am while running catchup. But after setting min_file_process_interval=60 the next day's dag triggers as soon as the previous day's dag execution is complete, or 1 minute after the previous day dag started in case the previous day dag completed in under a minute.